# not extract .zip files after download using PHP

Tags: php

I download my back file with `.zip` format using this PHP class:

```
public function download($file)
    {
        $filename = $this->dir . $file;
        $fp = fopen($filename, "rb");
        header("Pragma: public");
        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Cache-Control: public");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-length: " . filesize($filename));
        header("Content-disposition: attachment;filename = " . $file . "");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        readfile($filename);
        ob_end_clean();
        die(fpassthru($fp));
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

this worked and i downloaded `.zip` file successful. but when i need to extract `.zip` file using winrar i see this error:

`db-backup-2014-11-15_14-18-48-12.zip: The archive is either in unknown format or damaged`.

in download :

[image]

in open:

[image]

in extract :

[image]

**NOTE:** my original file worked and fine extracted using winrar.

i think my problem is CRC32 = 0000000 (in screen one) because in original file is have a true value.

how do fix this problem ?!

Comment: Open the .zip file in a texteditor like notepad++. U'd be able to see a warning/error/php output in there. Thats why the .zip file is corrupted

Comment: @DarkBee: You right. download zip with original zip is Difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ZIP file is most likely corrupted because your PHP script contains white space after closing `?>` tag which pollutes ZIP content. To solve this, remove PHP closing tag `?>` from your script that function `download()` is part of (also check if you do not have leading white-spaces, placed before opening `<?php` tag too) and your issue should be gone. If you include other scripts, check them for spaces too. In general `?>` tag should not be used, unless you are sure you need it it for known reason (which is very rare case).

Comment: i check my code but not found any space after `?>` tag. i create `.zip` using my code and this file worked and extracted. my problem when if download same file using php i see this error.

Comment: It does not necessary need to be **after** `?>` - this is just most common case with this issue, but it can be anywhere in your code. Additionally, if you are mixing HTML with PHP (and not use templates etc) then chances you step on this are higher. Basically the point is that something is being send to the browser along your zip content. Open your ZIP file in text editor or hex editor and see what is at the beginning of the file, compare with correct ZIP archive and then look where you can leak this character.

Comment: You right. download zip with original zip is Difference. download zip: http://jscdn.96.lt/pic/down.png original zip: http://jscdn.96.lt/pic/ori.png. how do find what's problem?

Comment: Please note that space before starting tag of php (<?php) also causes the zip file corrupt error.

Answer (score 7):

Try this download function instead :

```
<?php    
    public function download($file)  {
        ob_end_clean();
        $filename = $this->dir . $file;
        header("Content-Type: application/zip");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". pathinfo($filename , PATHINFO_BASENAME));
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize($filename ));
        readfile($fileName);
    }
```

Comment: ob_end_clean(); fixed my problem as well, Thank you